# Запись параметров объекта

Tags: java, матрицы, параметры

Есть `матрица`, состоящая из квадратиков. Каждый квадратик имеет свои *параметры*, а точнее: **Позиция X**, **позиция Y**, **уровень увеличения**.

Эти квадратики я получаю так:

```
public BufferedImage[][] test(BufferedImage img, int zoom) throws IOException {
        imageTile = img;
        width = getWidthSquare();
        height = getHeightSquare();

        col = getCountSquare(zoom);
        row = getCountSquare(zoom);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        tileset = new BufferedImage[col][row];

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {                 
                tileset[j][i] = imageTile.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);

                x += width;
            } // end for loop

            y += height;
            x = 0;
        } // end for loop

        return tileset;
}
```

Как мне записать их так, чтобы вместе с тем, что я буду передавать на запись в **БД** были эти данные об этом квадратике (положение Х,У и прочие)?

Знакомый посоветовал сделать [interface](/questions/tagged/interface) и туда передать, но если честно, то я его не понял.

Comment: При чем здесь необычность записей ArrayList ?

Comment: @pavlofff изменил.

Comment: Теперь при чем здесь обычность записей в ArrayList ? Вам надо продублировать записи из БД в ArrayList или что? Сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы и другим был понятно, что вы хотите получить

Comment: @pavlofff пожалуйста, по делу. Если видите что-то, чего не вижу я, просто подскажите, а не трольте.

Comment: Нет, я как раз не вижу, какая же у вас проблема. Суть вопроса абсолютно не понятна.

Comment: @pavlofff Что не понятного ? 
Есть квадрат у которого есть координаты. Каким способом и во что мне можно записать этот квадрат с координатами. То есть что бы в будущем я мог достать из чего то этот квадрат и его координаты. Что бы записать его в БД с его данными. 
Пример.
Есть матрица 2х2. Достаю второй квадрат (его координаты будут X0Y1) Куда можно записать этот квадрат (он типа JPG) с его этими координатами (массив или что предложите ?) Что бы целая матрица хранилась в неком массиве и можно было потом их доставать вместе с их координатами. Так понятнее ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения нужных вам полей вы можете определить свой класс. В вашем примере это `x`, `y`, `zoom`, `image`:

```
public class CellItem
{
    public BufferedImage Image;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Zoom;
}
```

И изменить метод для работы с новым типом:

```
public CellItem[][] test(BufferedImage img, int zoom) throws IOException {
    imageTile = img;
    width = getWidthSquare();
    height = getHeightSquare();

    col = getCountSquare(zoom);
    row = getCountSquare(zoom);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    tileset = new CellItem[col][row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

            CellItem cell = new CellItem();
            cell.Image = imageTile.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
            cell.X = x;
            cell.Y = y;
            cell.Zoom = zoom;
            tileset[j][i] = cell;

            x += width;
        } // end for loop

        y += height;
        x = 0;
    } // end for loop

    return tileset;
}
```

Метод вернет матрицу `CellItem`. Для каждой ячейки будут доступны четыре параметра. Работать с ними можно, например, так:

```
CellItem[][] cells = test(img, 1);
BufferedImage image = cells[0][0].Image;
int x = cells[0][0].X;
//...
```

Так как для всей ячеек у вас `zoom` имеет одинаковое значение, вы можете немного улучшить результат. Создав класс контейнер для двухмерного массива и поля `Zoom` и возвращать его:

```
public class CellContainer
{
    public CellItem[][] Cells;
    public int Zoom;
}

public class CellItem
{
    public BufferedImage Image;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Аналогично нужно будет поменять код метода `test` под новую структуру. Это уже на самостоятельную проработку ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое, что разобрались в моем вопросе !)
А можно вместо класса (который для хранения) использовать интерфейс тут ?

Comment: Интерфейс использовать можно, но вместе с классом. То есть у вас будет интерфейс ICellItem, а класс CellItem будет реализовывать этот интерфейс. Возвращать метод будет матрицу интерфейсов, но внутри будут все равно классы. В данной задаче совершенно спокойно можно без интерфейсов обойтись :)

Comment: Главное, что бы потом я мог спокойно из этого класса записать в БД ) но вроде все огонь. Спасибо большое еще раз !!! Благодаря stackoverflow каждый день узнаю новое )